# How to merge and handle 2 symfony forms in one?

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 symfony forms:

`SignupFormType` and `HouseRentFormType`

Signup form look like:

```
<form ..>
<input name='email' .. />
<input name='pass' .. />
..
</form>
```

And the House rent form like this:

```
<form ..>
<input name='city' .. />
<input name='price' .. />
</form ..>
```

I want to combine them so they look like this:

```
<form ..>
// house rent info:
<input name='city' .. />
<input name='price' .. />

//registration info:
<input name='email' .. />
<input name='pass' .. />
<input type='submit' />
</form ..>
```

And also to create a form type or smthng. 
Any tips on how to handle the submit?

p.s. I'm using symfony/form: ^3.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Symfony forms, everything is a form type. So one from has a root type, with child types. Each child type can have other child types, etc.

So in this case, you have 2 form types: `SignupFormType` and `HouseRentFormType`. You can use these as child types of a new form:

```
$form = $formBuilder
    ->add('signup', SignupFormType::class)
    ->add('house_rent', HouseRentFormType::class)
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: We work with the same solution, but we can't validate (isValid()) both forms, do you know a trick?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to extend @Wouter J's answer, because it didn't work for me the way above.

I had to define the data_class in the formbuilder:

```
class SignupHouseRentFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('signup', SignupFormType::class, array(
                'data_class' => Signup::class
            ))
            ->add('house_rent', HouseRentFormType::class, array(
                'data_class' => HouseRent::class
            ));
    }
}
```

then in the controller I had to use same namespace for the data binding:

```
class SignupHouseRentController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $signup    = new Signup();
        $houseRent = new HouseRent();

        $mergedData = array(
            'signup'    => $signup,
            'houseRent' => $houseRent
        );

        $form = $this->createForm(SignupHouseRentFormType::class, $mergedData);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }
}
```