# How to merge two symfony forms in one refering to the same class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

In my project I am having 2 forms, one is `UserForm1.php` and the second is `UserForm2.php`. I would like to use both of these complexe forms without remaking them in a form type like `FullUserForm.php`.

Has someone a tricks to do it ?

I though about making the `FullUserFrom.php` with all fields and then use in the classes `UserForm1.php` and `UserForm2.php` with options but I would like to do it the other way.

Thanks you in advance for your help !

Comment: Maybe this could help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355931/how-to-merge-2-form-in-symfony2

Comment: Both of my forms have the same ```data_class``` and I would like them to be merged in one single FormType having also the same ```data_class```, so it doesn't really help me

Comment: Both of your forms should have their own form type class see https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html. You can merge those type classes in a new one as @BranimirĐurek said (altho the answer is for older symfony, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254110/how-to-merge-and-handle-2-symfony-forms-in-one for recent symfony version). Another way would be to have one form type for both and use validation groups.

Comment: Your link is showing the classical case where 2 forms types are used together. My 2 forms types are referencing to the same entity, so merging theme as shown in your example is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to create one single class, but if both form are going to target the same data_class, I'm not sure you're taking the best approach.

I think you could have one form and based on the data, add the required fields and constraints. This can be easily done by passing options to the form, or with a more elegant solution, using an EventSubscriber as described here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: This is the right approach, having two forms for single class does not make sense, thats why there is group validation and event subscribers