# Initialize custom type form data

Tags: symfony, symfony2-forms

I have defined a custom form like this:

```
class EditOwnerProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("user", new UserType())
            ->add("dog", new DogType())
            ->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'edit_owner';
    }
}
```

I want to create this form and initialize it with some data like this:

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->setLatitude(1.1)
        ->setLongitude(2.2)
        ->setAddress("custom address");

    $dog = new Dog();
    $dog->setDogName("Bruno")
        ->setDogSize("small")
        ->setDogBreed("Bulldog");

    $formData = array(
        "user" => $user,
        "dog" => $dog
    );

    $form = $this->createForm(new EditOwnerProfileType(), $formData, array("csrf_protection" => false))->handleRequest($request);
```

`DogType`and `UserType`only have `NotBlank` constraints

Every time i want to validate data, it allways throws error for every field like this:

```
"errors": {
  "user": {
    "latitude": [
      "This value should not be blank."
    ],
    "longitude": [
      "This value should not be blank."
    ],
    "address": [
      "This value should not be blank."
    ]
  },
  "dog": {
    "dogName": [
      "This value should not be blank."
    ],
    "dogSize": [
      "This value should not be blank."
    ],
    "dogBreed": [
      "This value should not be blank."
    ]
  },
```

Isn't supposed that i'm initializing all the values? So, if user don't pass any value for this field, is initialized with the values I defined?
Which is the correct way to initialize values on `EditOwnerProfileType` form?

EDIT: I tried to change the form creation (just for testing), but didn't work either.

```
$form = $this->createForm(new EditOwnerProfileType(), $formData, array("csrf_protection" => false));
$form->setData($formData);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

EDIT2: To include DogType and UserType code

```
class DogType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('dogSize')
            ->add('dogBreed')            
        ;
    }    

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Dog',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'dog_type';
    }
}

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('latitude')
            ->add('longitude')
            ->add('address')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_type';
    }
}
```

I'm using Symfony 2.7.9

Comment: What is the data_class for EditOwnerProfileType ??

Comment: It has no data_class... is a custom form who embed other form types... do i need to create a class for it?

Comment: I think that is a way. The problem seem to be when you initialize each form in the buildForm function. There is no user or dog related to wherever entity related. So you need to build that entity or set the data attribute after that line http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data

Comment: `DogType` is tied to `Dog` class... and `UserType` is tied to `User` class... Its supossed that second parameter of createForm is the `data` no?

Comment: Seems like it should work.  Maybe show your DogType in the question.  Are you getting the expected values when you view the form in your browser?Which version of S2 are you using?  2.8/3.0 have some significant changes.

Comment: Thank you... i updated my question.

Comment: Passing the `$formData` has the same effect as passing `null`

Comment: I just found that if I call `$form->handleRequest($request)` at this point is where the $formData is resetted, any idea why? Im trying to call this only with one parameter `edit_owner[dog][name]=asd`, but all parameters get blank

Comment: So you are fooling around with request parameters?  That is not going to end well.

Comment: Can you explain me what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, the problem was... 
I was misunderstanding the Symfony Form Component.

I can initialize the form like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setLatitude(1.1)
    ->setLongitude(2.2)
    ->setAddress("custom address");

$dog = new Dog();
$dog->setDogName("Bruno")
    ->setDogSize("small")
    ->setDogBreed("Bulldog");

$formData = array(
    "user" => $user,
    "dog" => $dog
);

$form = $this->createForm(new EditOwnerProfileType(), $formData, array("csrf_protection" => false))
```

At this point, the form is correctly initialized and all fields have the correct values.

Passing one parameter in the request `edit_owner[dog][name]=othername` and doing:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I expected only the `edit_owner[dog][name]` to be changed (And the rest of fields maintain its default value), but i noticed that the rest of fields of the form were processed and parsed as `blank` values and replaced my "initial values".

That was the problem and Symfony works on that way.
I make this answer so it can be useful for someone else.